# Rag doll in game engine?

Tags: game-engine, rigging, armature, physics

I've seen some videos on a working rag doll in the game-engine, and I've always wondered on how to make one. Also, if I a rag doll effect is created, I need it to *not* be affected by animations (i.e. animations wont be playing anymore). I have some more to add to this, but I want to keep this as simple as possible so I will ask those in the future.

Comment: I'll post the answer in a hour or so... I'm so glad someone finally asked this :D :D :D :D

Comment: @Vince Scalia you know you could of just asked it and answered it, right?

Comment: yeah, that take all the fun out of it

Answer (score 1):

Create two rigid body armatures, one with animations, and one without animations. Constrain the bones of the rag doll to the rigid objects. switch between the both of them at the moment you want to let it fall. You should probably create a python script where you copy the location and orientation of the animated armature to the rigid objects. After that you just set the animated armature to invisible, and the other to visible.

Comment: If it works for you, then I presume you have a .blend. Would you mind sharing it? Thanks.

Comment: i probably do :) , i'll upload it for you as soon as i have a bit more time.

Comment: i don't seem to have that file anymore, but i found the video tutorial of which i learned it myself. [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EPsfOamN2XI). i'll try to recreate it, but that will take some time